# Did source map be overriding everytime i build app in sentry?

Tags: react-native, sentry

I have react native project. (Both iOS, Android).
I use sentry in the project.

Did source map be overriding every time I build app? Even in the development process?

How do I prevent it?

P/s:

I do the same guide in the below document.

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/

Answer (score 0):

no, that's not correct, running the App. in debug mode, it does symbolication on the device.